# Ruby on Rails Uninitialized constant SomeModule::SomeClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this class under `lib/some_module` in my project:

```
module SomeModule
  class SomeClass
    def initialize
    end
  end
end
```

When I go into `rails console` and I type in `SomeModule::SomeClass.new`, it works just finel.  But when I start up the server and try and access it from some other class, I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant SomeModule::SomeClass
```

I have added lib to my autoload in Application.rb. Not sure what might be going wrong

Comment: Have you remembered about restarting server when changing application.rb? ;)
Edit: Can you paste your autoload lines from application.rb?

Comment: @Esse yes I did `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/some_module`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add wildcard path to autoload (I'm not sure why - this fixed this error on my machine).

Therefore, add to application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```